# php calling several functions within for loop

Tags: php, function, loops, for-loop

Is it possible to call functions within for loops?  I have a number of databases that are exactly the same, I would like to use a for loop to set up the connections one at a time (35 databases).  I am having trouble with getting php to declare a function with a variable in the name.

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 35; $i++) 
{
    $j=$i+2;
    echo "<br><br>DB $i";
    $connection$j = prodDB$i();
    $getFromDB = "select URL, count(id) as counts from ProductList GROUP BY URL";
    $NamesReturned = mysqli_query($connection$j,$getFromDB) or die("Can't execute query GFNFDB.<br><br>$getFromDB<br><br>");
    while ($ret=mysqli_fetch_array($NamesReturned))
    {
        $DB$icounts=$ret["counts"];
        $URL=$ret["URL"];
        echo "<br>$DB$icounts -- $URL";
    }
    echo "<br>$DB$icounts";
}
```

Comment: what is `$connection$j` and `prodDB$i();` it is syntax error

Comment: @IlyaBursov Hence my problem.  I have 35 functions set up, each connecting to a different database.  I want this loop to connect to each of the databases 1 - 35, using its respective function and returning the unique connection string.

Comment: try `$q = 'prodDB'.$i;print_r($q());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you need to use is braces.   Eg: $connection{$j}=prodDB{$i}();

I could be wrong though.  It has been a long time since i did it.

You might be better using arrays and/or passing parameters to your functions.
Eg:

$connection[$j]=prodDB($i);